# gradle war vs gradle assemble (Grails 3.2.6 and Sec plugin 3.1.2)

Tags: tomcat, grails3, grails-spring-security

I am having really hard time figuring this one out. I have an app which works fine in intellij and as a standalone war (created with `gradlew assemble`). But when I am trying to deploy this war (created with `gradlew assemble` but with tomcat starter set as `provided` in build.gradle file) in the tomcat 8.5, I am getting this exception. But if I generate a war using `gradlew war` then I do not see this exception and tomcat is deployed alright. But in that case my app is giving all kind of crap errors on the front end related to gsps and g: namespace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findActionRoles(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:458)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findAnnotations(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:425)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findAnnotations(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findControllerAnnotations(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:382)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.initialize(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:223)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition$initialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.initializeFromAnnotations(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:770)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:651)
    at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:523)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:246)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:389)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5205)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

I am really unable to why this is happening ? This is my `application.groovy` file (security related configuration)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'my.domain.Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'my.domain.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Annotation' //"InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'MD5'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false // make this true only in dev mode. XXX
/**
 * Salting a password is a good strategy from security point of view.
 * @see  https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/#salt
 */
grails.plugin.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/error/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index.gsp', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/shutdown', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/assets/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/installrep/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/status/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/upgradeRepository/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/patchUpgradeRepository/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/log/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/help/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/login/**', access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/logout/**', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: '/assets*', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: 'js*', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: 'css*', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: 'images*', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: 'favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/endpoints*', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-filterInvocationInterceptor'],
        [pattern: '/services*', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-filterInvocationInterceptor'],
        [pattern: '/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]
```

Can somebody please help me understand what is going on ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I tracked down the code. First of all, the difference between grails run-app vs running a war owes it to two implementations of [AbstractGrailsApplication](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/core/AbstractGrailsApplication.java) class in grails-core. For war, DefaultGrailsApplication is used and for intellij and others, it uses StandaloneGrailsApplication.

And the problem in this case arises out of this function in DefaultGrailsApplication calls.

```
public GrailsClass getArtefact(String artefactType, String name) {
    ArtefactInfo info = getArtefactInfo(artefactType);
    return info == null ? null : info.getGrailsClass(name);
}
```

Apparently the artifact is being looked into cache. In case of tomcat, I had been seeing the warnings as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893297/tomcat-8-throwing-org-apache-catalina-webresources-cache-getresource-unable-to) here. And taking hints from that post, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37986333/1229355) and that does solve this issue here for me. I did not try by disabling the cache in tomcat. That probably might help as well. Let me know if you try that option out.

Hope this helps someone. I had been after this for more then a week now.

### Update and solution

Move the cfx dependency in gradle file above spring security plugin and then you should see spring security being configured once only. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680964/1229355).